# c# Arrays - Index Out of Range Exception

Tags: c#, arrays

I am getting indexoutofrangeexception (see ----> pointer for the line generating the error down below in the code).  The program loops through the header and line item records in a dataset tables.  The tables have a relationship.  My sample data has 2 headers, each with 2 lines.  The progam has two loops, the first one loops through the header records and the second one loops through the child records of the header.

Part of the program:

```
     // ***** PO Header and Line 

        int ln;
        ln = 0;

        // Create an eConnect PO Header node object
        taGLTransactionHeaderInsert jeh = new taGLTransactionHeaderInsert();

        // Create an array for lineitems
        taGLTransactionLineInsert_ItemsTaGLTransactionLineInsert[] lineitems = new   taGLTransactionLineInsert_ItemsTaGLTransactionLineInsert[ln];

        foreach (DataRow dtrHDR in ds.Tables["Header"].Rows)

        {
            Array.Clear(lineitems, 0, ln);

            jeh.BACHNUMB = "Sheraz";
            jeh.JRNENTRY = jenoint;
            jeh.REFRENCE = dtrHDR["Reference"].ToString();
            jeh.SOURCDOC = dtrHDR["AvantisJE"].ToString();
            jeh.USERID = System.Environment.UserName;
            jeh.TRXDATE = System.DateTime.Now.ToString();

            ln = 0;

            foreach (DataRow dtrLine in dtrHDR.GetChildRows("HdrLine"))

            {

                // Populate the elements of the taPoLIne_ItemsTaPOLine XML node
                taGLTransactionLineInsert_ItemsTaGLTransactionLineInsert jel = new taGLTransactionLineInsert_ItemsTaGLTransactionLineInsert();

                jel.BACHNUMB = jeh.BACHNUMB;
                jel.JRNENTRY = jeh.JRNENTRY;
                jel.ACTNUMST = dtrLine["GreatPlains"].ToString();
                jel.DEBITAMT = Convert.ToDecimal(dtrLine["Debit"].ToString());

                //Avantis Inv Trx Key
                jel.ORDOCNUM = dtrLine["AvantisJE_Line"].ToString();
                // Avantis GL Trx Type
                jel.ORTRXDESC = dtrLine["transactiontypename"].ToString();


                //Add POLine to an Array
                lineitems[ln] = jel;     ----------------> I get an error here!

                ln = ln + 1;

                Array.Resize(ref lineitems, ln + 1);

            }

        }
```

Comment: how did you  initialize your array

Comment: taGLTransactionLineInsert_ItemsTaGLTransactionLineInsert[] lineitems = new   taGLTransactionLineInsert_ItemsTaGLTransactionLineInsert[ln];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are accessing an index that doesn't yet exist.

```
//Add POLine to an Array
lineitems[ln] = jel;     ----------------> I get an error here!
ln = ln + 1;     
Array.Resize(ref lineitems, ln + 1);
```

You need to change the order to :

```
//Add POLine to an Array
Array.Resize(ref lineitems, ln + 1);
lineitems[ln] = jel;     ----------------> should be fixed, no error here!
ln = ln + 1;
```

EDIT: Now that the immediate problem is out of the way, on to a better implementation.

Arrays are of a fixed sized, resizing an array is an expensive operation (basically it entails creating a copy with a new size). typically you would use these after identifying a performance bottle neck. In most cases it would be much better to use a List.

I'd recommend changing this line:

```
// Create an array for lineitems
taGLTransactionLineInsert_ItemsTaGLTransactionLineInsert[] lineitems = 
              new    taGLTransactionLineInsert_ItemsTaGLTransactionLineInsert[ln];
```

to:

```
var lineitems = new  List<taGLTransactionLineInsert_ItemsTaGLTransactionLineInsert>();
```

and then to add to it you simply do

```
lineitems.Add(jel);
```

to iterate over them would be:

```
for (var ln in lineitems) {
 // whatever you want to do with a line.
}
```

to acccess a specific item by index would be:

```
lineitems.Item(i); // get the ith item in the list.
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because you created an array with 0 elements and try to insert an element on position 0. This will not work. You can fix it by declaring the array with a size of 1 to begin with:

```
// Create an array for lineitems
taGLTransactionLineInsert_ItemsTaGLTransactionLineInsert[] lineitems = new   taGLTransactionLineInsert_ItemsTaGLTransactionLineInsert[1];
```

However, resizing an array on the fly is not the idiomatic .NET way of doing this. You could use a `List<T>`, which takes care of resizing for you, and leaving you with cleaner code and possibly better performance.

Comment: Yes, declaring the array with a size of 1 worked.  I am going to look into the List<T> now to see if I can clean up the code a bit.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you're trying to increase the size of the array by setting a value, like you might do in JavaScript.  C# arrays are not like that.  You need to create them at the size you want them to be when finished.

Alternately, you could use a `List` object, using the Add() method to put new content into the list.

Answer (score 0):

`lineitems` is obviously not the same size as the row collection returned by `dtrHDR.GetChildRows("HdrLine")`.  You are creating an array of zero elements and then trying to index into it.  If you want it to match the size of `dtrHDR.GetChildRows("HdrLine")` then you need to call that first and initialize the array after you can get the count.

Instead of using an array why don't you use a `List<T>` and just push items onto it?  No need to worry about `IndexOutOfRange` exceptions anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the array before putting anything in to it.  call the .resize first.

Answer (score 0):

those lines are the problem

```
 int ln;
 ln = 0;

 // Create an array for lineitems
 taGLTransactionLineInsert_ItemsTaGLTransactionLineInsert[] lineitems = new   taGLTransactionLineInsert_ItemsTaGLTransactionLineInsert[ln];
```

You create table of 0 elements.

Answer (score 0):

You have an off-by-one error in your program:

```
    int ln = 0
    .
    .
    .
    taGLTransactionLineInsert_ItemsTaGLTransactionLineInsert[] lineitems = new   taGLTransactionLineInsert_ItemsTaGLTransactionLineInsert[ln];
    .
    .
    .
    lineitems[ln] = jel;
```

You are initializing an array of 0 elements, then trying to set the first element (element[0]) to a value.